# Check same value in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following array:

```
$teams = [["id" => 1, "address" => "A1"],["id" => 2, "address" => "A1"],["id" => 3, "address" => "A2"]];
```

How can I check and get the teams with the same address? My output should be Team ID 1 and 2? Consider that I cannot use hard coded address. The data is dynamic and is coming from the database.

In php, laravel.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's many ways to skin this cat. I'd probably use a combination of `in_array()` and `array_column()` if the data set isn't too big.

Comment: Could you please give me an example based on my array? I cannot use 'A1' hardcoded.. because I don't know the address in the code.. I have to check where the addresses are the same and get the ids.

Comment: If I was doing this in Laravel I would rather try to do this grouping+filtering in the database instead. If you show the code that produces `$teams`, someone might be able to suggest something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) and [`array_count_values()`](https://php.net/array_count_values). Then use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) to remove elements with no duplicates:

```
$teams = [
 ["id" => 1, "address" => "A1"],
 ["id" => 2, "address" => "A1"] ,
 ["id" => 3, "address" => "A2"]
];

$dups = array_count_values(array_column($teams, 'address'));
$teams = array_filter($teams, function($item) use($dups) {
    return $dups[$item['address']] > 1;
});
print_r($teams);
```

Outputs (reformatted):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array([id] => 1, [address] => A1)
    [1] => Array([id] => 2, [address] => A1)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to group by their `address` and then you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to truncate your array based on criteria:

```
<?php
$teams = [["id" => 1, "address" => "A1"],["id" => 2, "address" => "A1"],["id" => 3, "address" => "A2"]];

// Set a new array
$filtered = [];

// Loop the teams
foreach($teams as $v)
{
    // Group the teams into their respective addresses
    $filtered[$v['address']][] = $v;
}

// Filter out any address with 1 or fewer teams
$filtered = array_filter($filtered, function($v){
    return count($v) > 1;
});

print_r($filtered);

// Now you can loop $filtered and display whatever you want
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [A1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [address] => A1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [address] => A1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I do not know the 'A1' addresses in the code and cannot be hardcoded. I have to check where the addresses are the same and get the team ids.

Comment: @codi05ro so you are looking to group these arrays based on `address`, right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. :)

Comment: Beat me to it, this is pretty much where I was going with my answer :)

Comment: @codi05ro So the result should only have teams which share an address? Is that why Team ID 3 is omitted from your question? Or do you just want everything, shared and unshared addresses?

Comment: @rickdenhaan apparently this answer is wrong so I just saved you some headache...

Comment: I want only the teams with shared addresses. Team 3 was just for example.

Comment: @codi05ro I've updated my answer. It has the essence of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50221021/2191572 but mine is more compact and uses `array_filter()`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus What's the point of copying an answer on the same question …

Comment: @AurelBílý My answer is definitely not a copy. I updated my answer per clarification from OP.

Comment: I like your answer Monkey, I've added one, just because I like to remove loop, but you got my point ;)

Comment: @Syscall Thanks. I was considering going the dense route like you did but I chose not to just for the sake of not making OP totally lost, especially with the closure `use()`, lol

Comment: This returns `Array ( [A1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [address] => A1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [address] => A1 ) ) ) `

Comment: @James Yes, my "Output" section exhibits this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the array, remember which addresses are used by which team. When there is more than one team stored at a key (address), you found a duplicate:

```php
<?php
$teams = [
     ["id" => 1, "address" => "A1"]
    ,["id" => 2, "address" => "A1"]
    ,["id" => 3, "address" => "A2"]
  ];

function findDuplicates($teams) {
  $addresses = [];
  foreach ($teams as $team) {
    if (!isset($addresses[$team["address"]])) {
      $addresses[$team["address"]] = [];
    }
    $addresses[$team["address"]][] = $team["id"];
  }
  foreach ($addresses as $address => $teamsHere) {
    if (count($teamsHere) > 1) {
      echo "Teams with same address (" . $address . "): " . join(",", $teamsHere) . "\n";
    }
  }
}

findDuplicates($teams);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZGxTsMwEIZ3P8XPqYMjRZVaNkpBSAw8AFvIYCWO4oo6UeyIAeXZg@2kcaoigSf77vt9/921dTuOj89t3bKNleJscETG4E9GqiQcn7BLQaIsO2lMeNPLjvLApAuz/wdzf8PsA5MfGKt6XVjVaFRKl699@6kKYaXhk6kE347bzGIZTDoVUDWdFEWNmYMwCLdJAKgK/E45ieVRnQUkW7zkeXLh10VusaUsMLC/4Mzjc9QNIOiGK8uxHW97fvnBTM28yU6u@yiaXlu@zrnVROOyqBvQexjDl7I1jDhLXH7lhG2ssQUlD/ChU6M0p5TSq6Iu/6Epdjqwwa3o180cxvEH)

---

Edit: a less "clunky" approach, using `array_*` functions:

```php
<?php
$teams = [
     ["id" => 1, "address" => "A1"]
    ,["id" => 2, "address" => "A1"]
    ,["id" => 3, "address" => "A2"]
  ];

function findDuplicates($teams) {
  $addresses = array_column($teams, "address");
  $counts = array_count_values($addresses);
  return array_filter($teams, function($team) use ($counts) { return $counts[$team["address"]] > 1; });
}

print_r(findDuplicates($teams));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNCoMwEEb3OcUQXCh0o11aWwq9hYgEjRjQGPJTKMWz2xhjENpFZzfDm29eInqxLJeb6AWKNCWjggJKBGuVmLUYiiukJ8CkbSVVyvX4nuLKMafAZH8w5y8mc0yVI9QZ3mg2cegYbx9GDKwhmqp4k0rgbbnIL9NVkkhJXnUzDWbknjrEJ/nKN5Ph@gjbtn6SwazBIcyxkmojuQc7NmgqQ@rutg0SMIpC7MOt2b7rJ6WjyqBSVWC/MIfZ3pkREpJZCRn/fmeSL8sH)

Comment: @James how's that